# Create a launcher app in android

Tags: android, android-launcher

I have searched a lot but did not find what i want so sorry if this is duplicate question..

i want to make a launcher app like [this](http://www.androidauthority.com/best-homescreen-launcher-apps-android-103889/) and [this](http://androidheadlines.com/2012/05/featured-top-10-best-android-launcher-apps.html) i gone through some tutorial but i just dont know from where i should start..please help

Answer will be greatly Appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: @Nik.... thanks for valuable reply ..i have tried this https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Launcher2/+/dca661236c73ecd819cfea964c6f8170e5cc40ae/src/com/android/launcher2/Launcher.java which contain these many classes actually https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Launcher2/+/dca661236c73ecd819cfea964c6f8170e5cc40ae/src/com/android/launcher2/  so really stuck i am

Comment: What is your question?  If you tried these, where did you get stuck?

Comment: @Simon actually this tutorial is totally confused me as i want just simple launcher app so is there any other tutorial from where i can start from scratches

Comment: so sad that i did not find a start bounty button as this question is too important for me

Comment: Any launcher is a complex app and, if you do not understand these tutorials, I recommend that you start with an easier app to develop.

Comment: @Simon thanks man for reply again..you right its a complex but my client will not allow me to leave so just diving into complexity..hope will come out with result..BTW +1 for comment and thanks a lot

Comment: If you are required to do a launcher, you could start by looking at the "Home" replacement in the SDK samples.

Comment: Have You success to make your custom Launcher??? i also want to make my custom Launcher for not come bake from my application by prassing any hard key of device. have u any idea???